# mySQL stored procedure not returning the value it should

Tags: php, mysql

Any idea why:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`%` PROCEDURE `getEventData` (IN id INT) 
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM
    `event` 
  WHERE `id` = id ;
END $$
```

Returns every row in the `event` table when there is only a single record with the id (which is the primary key) 4?

Answer (score 0):

Just so anyone else who has the same question is aware, apparently you can't use a parameter with the same name as the column you're checking.